# Validate custom form field in laravel auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1.9 LTS. I am using the out of the box laravel`s auth features. I added a new form field in registration and it is not being validated.
The new form field that I added.

```
 <div class="controls">
                                <div class="controls first">
                                    <select name="account_type" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="0" >Select the account type</option>
                                        <option value="1">Buyer</option>
                                        <option value="2">Seller</option>
                                        <option value="3">Agent</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <p class="help-block">
                                    {{ $errors->first('account_type') }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
```

The validation part

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'account_type' => 'required|min:1',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

I have also put account_type in the fillable protected variable but still it is not working

Comment: When you use `print_r($data);` willl give you a result?

Comment: @aldrin27 yes, I did dd($data) and it gave me value of account_type too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that account_type's value parameter is being returned as a string. When you call "min:1" on a string it will accept strings with a minimum **lenght** of 1, wich is the case in all options you have there.

You can try changing this line so it will return a string with zero lenght/null:

```
<option value>Select the account type</option>
```

You could remove the rule "min:1" and leave it just as "required".